# Yaml schema Validation powershell

Tags: powershell, yaml

I'm working with [powershell-yaml](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/powershell-yaml/0.4.0) to parse my YAML into a PowerShell object.

currently, I have a problem validating my YAML schema. I've used this package [yaml-schema-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-schema-validator) for my javascript project and I couldn't find any familiar function\moudle to help me solve this problem with Powershell.

Is There a schema validation language for YAML in Powershell?

Comment: not a validator, but some cmdlets that might help you out: https://github.com/cloudbase/powershell-yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, no, I don't believe there are any Powershell native options for doc validation against a YAML schema.

Since YAML is a super-set of JSON, one could (depending on the YAML being validated), use a schema expressed in JSON and validated w/[Test-JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json?view=powershell-6).

There are two active YAML modules I'm aware of: (1) PSYaml and (2) powershell-yaml. The second being what you use today. I don't believe either of them validate YAML docs against a schema.

I believe there are schema validation modules/projects in the following:

- Ruby
- Python
- PHP
- JavaScript

You can see the list in [Schema Validation for YAML](https://json-schema-everywhere.github.io/yaml).

You could always do you validation in another language, and wrap that call in Powershell. You just have to handle the integration yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the general correct suggestion from [@Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8803234/adam), I have not been able to get this to work with native PowerShell/.Net using the [[Newtonsoft.json] classes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) (see also: [`Test-Json` (validate schema) in Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75758474/1701026)).

Nevertheless, here is a cumbersome way (converting everything to `Json` first) to do this in PowerShell 7:

```
Install-Module powershell-yaml

function Test-Yaml {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='__AllParameterSets', HelpUri='https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2096609')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]
        ${Yaml},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='SchemaString', Position=1)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        ${Schema},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='SchemaFile', Position=1)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        ${SchemaFile})

    begin {
        function Yaml2Json ($Yaml) { $Yaml |ConvertFrom-Yaml |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 64 }
        $outBuffer = $null
        if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer)) { $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1 }
        $Parameters = @{}
        foreach($PSBoundParameters in $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator()) {
            switch ($PSBoundParameters.Key) {
                'Yaml'       { $Parameters['Json']   = Yaml2Json $PSBoundParameters.Value }
                'Schema'     { $Parameters['Schema'] = Yaml2Json $PSBoundParameters.Value }
                'SchemaFile' { $Parameters['Schema'] = Yaml2Json (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $PSBoundParameters.Value) }
                Default      { $Parameters[$PSBoundParameters.Key] = $PSBoundParameters.Value }
            }
        }

        $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Test-Json', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
        $scriptCmd = { & $wrappedCmd @Parameters }

        $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
        $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
    }

    process {
        $Json = Yaml2Json $_
        $steppablePipeline.Process($Json)
    }

    end {
        $steppablePipeline.End()
    }

    clean
    {
        if ($null -ne $steppablePipeline) {
            $steppablePipeline.Clean()
        }
    }
}
```

```
$YamlSchema = @'
description: A person
type: object
required:
- name
- hobbies
properties:
  name:
    type: string
  hobbies:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
'@
```

```
$Yaml = @'
name: James
hobbies:
- .NET
- Blogging
- Reading
- Xbox
- LOLCATS
'@

$Yaml |Test-Yaml -Schema $YamlSchema
True
```

```
$Yaml = @'
test: James
hobbies:
- .NET
- Blogging
- Reading
- Xbox
- LOLCATS
'@

$Yaml |Test-Yaml -Schema $YamlSchema
Test-Json: PropertyRequired: #/name
False
```