# Test-Json (validate schema) in Windows PowerShell

Tags: json, .net, powershell, testing, schema

I would like to validate my Json against a Json Schema in **Windows PowerShell**

For PowerShell 7, you might use [`Test-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json) for this:

```
$Json = @'
{
  "name": "James",
  "hobbies": [".NET", "Blogging", "Reading", "Xbox", "LOLCATS"]
}
'@

$JsonSchema = @'
{
  "description": "A person",
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["name", "hobbies"],
  "properties":
  {
    "name": {"type":"string"},
    "hobbies": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {"type":"string"}
    }
  }
}
'@

Test-Json -Json $Json -Schema $JsonSchema
True
```

But when I try to do something similar with the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) class (standard available in PowerShell 7), I get an error:

```
$Schema = [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema]::Parse($JsonSchema)
$JObject = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($Json)
$JObject.IsValid($Schema)

OperationStopped: C:\Users\Gebruiker\GDrive\Scripts\PowerShell\_JIO\Yaml\Test-Yaml.ps1:31
Line |
  31 |  $JObject.IsValid($Schema)
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Target type System.Collections.IEnumerator is not a value type or a non-abstract class. (Parameter 'targetType')
```

How can I fix this or workaround this?

References:

- [Understanding NewtonSoft in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58141125/1701026)
- [`#10652` Working directly with certain .NET types, such as Newtonsoft.Json's, is broken: implicit stringification](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10652)

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the official `JToken.IsValid()` examples working in Windows PowerShell either, but I found that using a "validating reader" works:

```
using namespace System.IO
using namespace Newtonsoft.Json

# Create a read around the JSON string
$reader = [JsonTextReader]::new([StringReader]::new($Json))

# Create a validator around the reader, attach governing schema
$validator = [JsonValidatingReader]::new($reader)
$validator.Schema = $schema

# Create a serializer
$serializer = $serializer = [JsonSerializer]::new()

try {
  # attempt to deserializer input json via validator
  $null = $serializer.Deserialize($validator)

  # schema validation must have succeeded
}
catch [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaException] {
  # schema validation must have failed
}
catch {
  # something else went wrong
}
finally {
  # Clean up
  $reader, $validator |% Dispose
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but unfortunately it appears to also have issues with the newtonsoft object format. This didn't appear from my orginal [mcve]. I have updated the question with a new schema, including an additinal array: `"required": ["name", "hobbies"],` which fails with an error: `Cannot convert value "{ ... }" to type "Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema". Error: "Can not convert Array to Boolean`

Comment: I think I need to try this approach with [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft). Later this weekend...